# How can I a create thumbnail for any files like (image, video, PDF, .xlsx, .ai, etc) using carrierwave in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, imagemagick, carrierwave

I've tried with

```
system("convert -strip -thumbnail '100x>' #{org_file.file}[0] #{thumb}.png")
```

but this is not working on Heroku..

Is there any way to create a thumbnail?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define it in your uploader

```
#Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  end
```

[checkout this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-create-a-thumbnail-with-both-color-and-grayscale-versions-in-one-image)

Comment: I've defined and it's working in local machine  but not working in Heroku

Comment: @SubhasisGiri Ohhoo, do you know that heroku doesn't give any extra space to upload file.? for this you will have to use any cloud storage like- aws bucket...etc.

Comment: i'm using fog for that but when i'm running this command in local thats create thumbnail for me .

But in heroku giving error to me

 $ convert -strip -thumbnail '50x>' small.3gp[0] thumbnail.png
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `3GP' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined `thumbnail.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.

Comment: @SubhasisGiri I m not sure whether carrierwave is able to create thumbnail for videos as well.

Comment: Except image, all other mime-types are giving errors on heroku, But in locals every things working fine. Is there any policy or size  related issue in heroku?.